# Is it possible to simulate an RFID card reader and listen for its events?

Tags: javascript, html

Our company uses card readers such as: https://stid-security.com/en/products/arc-a-13-56-mhz-desfire-ev3-standard-rfid-readers

What it does is that when you place a card close to the reader, it reads the data (number in my case), then whichever text area in the browser is in focus - it will write the number down and also click Enter.

It can be a text input, textarea or even the address bar. (And if there is no focus, it will not write anything)

I currently don't have the reader. Is it possible to simulate the actions that the reader does, and, also catch the event, if such exists? Because I might want to prevent it from automatically pressing Enter, or put the focus on another predefined input so that the number will be written there.

Thanks.

Comment: isn't javascript have `focus` event for input boxes?

Comment: Yes, but the card reader just writes the information down even if there is no focus so I need to catch the event before and then I can do focus myself

Comment: Is Javascript the best language while it is easily changeable by any user through the dev console? Makes it sense to use a security in the form of a RFID and then use an open fronent solution to use and work with that information?

Comment: So the card reader is basically doing keyboard actions. Putting content into the input field (copy paste or individual keystrokes) and pressing enter. You could simulate this by creating a makro for your keyboard / mouse with predefined actions. After hitting enter, a form is submitted, so you would have listen to the forms `submit` event with JavaScript.

Comment: Have a look on this https://github.com/CarlRaymond/jquery.cardswipe

Comment: @AlexBerger is certainly right. There is no special event or special anything. The device sends keystrokes just like the keyboard would. Basically, this means that you can easily "emulate" the device's behaviour by... pressing random numbers + enter key. I'm betting that even without focus on an input, the window object receives the keystroke events. Maybe you could use that?